# FreeIPA krb5.conf has example.com entries

Tags: ldap, kerberos, freeipa

I have installed and reinstalled FreeIPA ipa-server-3.0.0-37.el6.x86_64 on a fully updated OEL 6.5 server a couple (3) times now and even if I destroy the existing /etc/krb5.conf file and reinstall ipa-server, the krb5.conf files ends up with this example.com crap in the file. Does it server a purpose? I can't imagine how. Chopping it out seems to make no difference, kinit thinks I'm in example.com realm.

```
EXAMPLE.COM = {
kdc = kerberos.example.com
admin_server = freeipa-poc01.bo3.edurp.com:749
}

[domain_realm]
.bo3.edurp.com = AD.EDURP.COM
bo3.edurp.com = AD.EDURP.COM

example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
.example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
[dbmodules]
AD.EDURP.COM = {
db_library = ipadb.so
}
```

Comment: Try joining your computer to a domain, first.

Comment: Are you saying the example.com is expected?

Comment: Are you saying that isn't the content of the file _after_ joining the computer to the domain?

Comment: The example.com was being sucked in from /etc/sssd/sssd.conf, which was configured for a different (old) auth scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Watch out for /etc/sssd/sssd.conf. The installer pulls in values from sssd.conf.